# Kafka Rejoining Group Quite Frequently

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot application which consists of 10 different consumers , trying to consume messages from 10 different topics. The application uses same consumer group as all the 10 different topics are listed under the same consumer group. Now after a while of running the application (After 5 hours) , I am seeing the consumers going are trying to rebalance , and at times the rebalances never finishes hence unable to receive the messages after a while.

Here is my consumer configuration.

```
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(String clientID) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);
    props.put(SECURITY_PROTOCOL, securityProtocol);
    props.put(SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
    props.put(SASL_JAAS_CONFIG,
            String.format("%s required username=\"%s\" password=\"%s\" ;", loginModule, username, kafkaSecretPass));

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 5);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 10000);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientID);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
   //props.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
  //props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
  //props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 600000);
 //props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 2097164);
 //props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
     return props;
}
```

Here is the error I see after running the consumer for a while.

```
[Consumer clientId=consumer-one, groupId=group-1] (Re-)joining group
```

This attempt to rejoin the group goes on a for a long time , eventually it is never able to join the group.

Here is how one of the consumer is consuming the topic and sending it for processing.

```
  @EventListener(ApplicationStartedEvent.class)
public Disposable consume() {
    return reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate
            .receive()
            .concatMap(consumerRecord -> {
                log.info("Received event:customer offset {} and value {}",
                        consumerRecord.offset(),new String(consumerRecord.value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                return updateCustomer(consumerRecord).flatMap(success -> {
                    consumerRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                    return Mono.just("Received");
                });
            })
            .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)).transientErrors(true))
            .onErrorResume(e -> {
                log.info("Customer - Receiver On Error Resume");
                return Mono.empty();
            })
            .repeat()
            .subscribe(suc -> log.info("Subscribe successfully in Customer"), err -> log.error("Error occurred during subscribe Customer, " + err));
}
```

Comment: ```The application uses same consumer group as all the 10 different topics are listed under the same consumer group ``` - what do you mean by ``` all the 10 different topics are listed under the same consumer group``` - how are you saying that topics are under a group . are you referring to partitions in a topic?

Comment: Also add how are you subscribing a topic / assigning a topic to a consumer. That might add clarity

Comment: @Umeshwaran : Have added how we are subscribing to topic. ReactitveKafkaConsumer template is created out of the consumer config described above. Each of the topic has only single partition , and they all fall under single consumer group, which is described using       props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup);

Comment: There are more than one reason for consumer rebalancing . I have given the most common one. Try checking if the consumer takes too long to process the message. If that's not the case , try giving unique consumer group-id for each consumer so that other consumers from other topic can consume message without any issues

Comment: It is not good practice to use the same group id across unrelated topics - for exactly this reason; a rebalance on one topic causes a rebalance on all.

Comment: @GaryRussell , Is there anyway to identify which topic consumer is processing slow , hence triggering a rebalance .

Comment: Only by looking at the logs.

Comment: At the consumer side , I am not able to find out which consumer is triggering the rebalance, has it to be looked at from broker end ?

Comment: @GaryRussell I have 3 different application in which these 10 topics are distributed. Will the log for rebalancing,  be shown only in the application which causes it.?

Answer (score 2):

Frequent rebalances are usually caused because it is taking too long for the consumer to process batches. This happens because the consumer is processing the batch for a long time (and heartbeats are not being sent) and therefore the brokers think that consumer was lost and they start re-balancing.

I would either suggest to create smaller batches by reducing the value of `max.partition.fetch.bytes` or extend/increase heartbeat intervals by increasing the value of `heartbeat.interval.ms`.

For more info : [More info](https://www.google.com/search?q=kafka%20consumer%20rebalance%20frequently&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN980IN980&ei=J0QCYoXBFZ-94-EPgPyHmAE&oq=kafka%20consumer%20rebalance%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAULgJWLgJYMkTaAFwAngAgAFyiAFykgEDMC4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)